# How to handle data in multiple states to filter data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter data present in table with states. I have created 2 states 1st to store data in dropdown and 2nd to store data rendered in table.

For e.g.

```
this.state {
   dropdown:[],
   tabledata:[]
}
```

I'm setting data from two different rest endpoints to these 2 states. 1st state is used to bind data to dropdown and 2nd to bind data to table. How can I handle filter logic when I am selecting data from dropdown? based on the selected data same should be filtered in table.

Comment: Can you add the structure of one of the data items inside the dropdown and tabledata arrays.

Comment: dropdown: <select className="form-control" id="countries" name="Country" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                                <option>India</option>
                                <option>USA</option>
                            </select>

Comment: add some more code and the structure example of how these state variables actually look.

Comment: table array: renderTableData(data) {
    return this.state.tabledata.map((element, i) => (
      <tr key={i}> 
        <td>{element.Country}</td></tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropdown: [],
      data: [],
      filteredData: [],
    }
  }
  onDropdownChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      filteredData: this.state.data.filter(() => // put your condition and return the data)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onDropdownChange.bind(this)}>
          {
            this.state.dropdown.map((value) => <option value={value}>{value}</option>)
          }
        </select>
        <YourTable data={this.state.filteredData} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```